# Very large mysql Insert query taking lifetime to execute

Tags: mysql, node.js, google-app-engine, request

I am executing a mysql insert query having very large amount of linestring data. but it's taking infinite time to execute the query. (insert query is so big that it takes more than 5 minutes to paste on the terminal).

My content-length is 10 mb as per request header. so i thought it must be due to mysql query size but that is 34mb. i also increase connection timeout to infinite but still it's not executing.

```
Insert into table (id,data) value (1,LinestringFromText('LINESTRING(0 9,8 0... so on and it goes on)'))
```

If i try the same query with the low amount of data it execute smoothly but with large amount of data it stucks.

Comment: Where is your mysql server? Consider adding some more code examples. Which driver(npm package) are you using to execute the `mysql` query.

Comment: mysql server is on appengine and i am using mysql npm package https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql. and i unable to print my whole query becuase it is so big. should i add any flag value in appenging db ?

Comment: @Stamos do you think somehow it is due to app engine restriction.

Comment: @Stamos it takes 35 minutes to perform the query. i think i can not do much except decrease query size.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't use an App Engine application to hold and run a mysql server, reasons being that you shouldn't rely on an App Engine instance to hold and serve dynamic data (see [how instances are managed](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/how-instances-are-managed)). However, if having your mysql server in App engine is a must, you can try to change the instance class of your application in the [`app.yaml`](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/nodejs/config/appref#instance_class) configuration file, to [one of the following](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/#instance_classes). A machine with more resources, should translate to a better performance.

However, I would recommend you to use [Cloud SQL](https://cloud.google.com/sql/) to hold and serve your data, and connect to it from your application. See [this tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/nodejs/getting-started/using-cloud-sql) for an overview on how can you do this, which is based in [this source code](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/nodejs-getting-started/tree/master/2-structured-data). This example also uses the [`mysql`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mysql) package that you linked.